# cPanel Select PHP Not enabled

Tags: cpanel

I'm running WHM 58.0 (build 31) under CENTOS 7.2 x86_64  with easyapache4, my issue is on my previous host ( shared one ) I had the option ' Select php version' under software, I have looked around and can't fin a solution to activate this.

how can I activate this and allow user to select their php versions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're talking about this button:

[image: button]

It's part of [CloudLinux](https://www.cloudlinux.com/). CloudLinux is an OS written specifically for shared hosting providers. I believe cPanel recommend them for new installations too ([here](http://cpanel.com/products/#cloudlinux) is a link for that).

cPanel recently introduced [MultiPHP](https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/ALD/MultiPHP+Manager+for+cPanel), which adds support for multiple PHP versions on one server and allows end users to pick their PHP version. I personally still prefer the CloudLinux PHP selector, though.

Comment: Thanks for the answer , yes I'm talking about select PHP version in the cpanel not WHM , I have used Easay apache 4 , and still can't see the select php function in client side

Comment: MultiPHP shows a different interface than the select PHP version interface from CloudLinux. I believe it's a separate feature you need to enable in the feature manager, and you also need to have multiple PHP versions installed using EA4.

Answer (score 0):

Select php version is available with Cloudlinux. For Centos, you can use the Multi php manager of cPanel inorder to change the php version for the Domain.

> https://manage.accuwebhosting.com/knowledgebase/2881/How-to-change-PHP-version-from-cPanel.html